# How to close Camera using phonegap-barcode-scanner plugin within service IONIC

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, phonegap-plugins, barcode-scanner

I am using phonegap-barcodescanner-plugin to read qr while a service is reading instant payments on background.

I am detecting a new instant payment in the service and launching an event subscribed in the page where the barcodeScanner is launched

```
event.subscribe('instant-payment', (val) => {
      console.log("Hi--------------", val)
      this.navCtrl.pop()
    });
```

the event is correctly fired and the log is ok but I'm trying to do a navCtrl.pop() and the Activity is never closed, I thought was going to work same way like cancelling scanner

```
 scan() {
    this.barcodeScanner.scan(this.options).then(barcodeData => {
      if (barcodeData.cancelled == true) {
        this.navCtrl.pop()
      } else {

      }
    }).catch(err => {
      console.log('Error', err);
    });
  }
```

Is there anyway to force close barcodeScanner and go back to the last "IonicPage".

Thanks for any help.

Comment: whats the error when u pop()

Comment: sometimes there is no view stacked to pop, sometimes no error but nothing happens.
Finally I decided to use cordova-plugin-qrscanner where you can call scanner.hide()/show() and its easier to customize the camera overlay.